Seeking Solutions for App Suspension in Google Play Console Due to Broken Functionality Policy Violation
I'm currently seeking assistance regarding an issue with one of my apps on the Google Play Console. The app, which is designed for safety procedures and reporting, has been suspended solely due to multiple violations of the broken functionality policy. It's a simple app aimed at facilitating safety protocols and generating reports.
Despite our efforts to rectify the issues and ensure compliance with Google Play policies, the app remains suspended. We've reached out to Google Play Support via email, but unfortunately, we haven't received any responses for the past six days.
I'm concerned that making another appeal might result in suspension of other app in play console. Hence, I'm seeking further guidance on how to proceed in this situation.
Has anyone encountered a similar scenario where an app has been suspended solely due to violations of the broken functionality policy? What steps can be taken to expedite the review process and ensure compliance with Google Play policies without risking account termination?
Any insights, advice, or recommendations would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance. Also attaching image of mail shared from play console after suspension of the app below.
Best regards,
Fellow Developer


https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Facing a similar problem. Have you solved it?

@Shahriar it is resolved as of now, you have to contact support team only & they will help you out for the same.
